# What is the packet count in timedatectl timesync-status command

Tags: linux, systemd, time-synchronization, systemd-timesyncd

I am trying to understand the output from the `timedatectl timesync-status` with an example shown below:

> ```
>    Server: 91.149.91.123 (ntp.ubuntu.com) Poll interval: 32s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s)
>      Leap: normal
>   Version: 4
>   Stratum: 2
> Reference: C0248F32
> Precision: 1us (-24) Root distance: 87.096ms (max: 5s)
>    Offset: -53.991ms
>     Delay: 208.839ms
>    Jitter: 0  Packet count: 1
> Frequency: -500,000ppm
> ```

Could someone explain (or refer me to documentation) about the meaning of packet count?